# How to make JAXB recognize different Classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've implemented JAXB to convert XML data to Object, here I've used like this.

Assume a new user is Registered. So I've to load the data in its appropriate class to store it in DB. So I used hard coded it as .newInstance(User.Class)

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
```

Now I've to do some Employer related functions. 
For that I need to have it as .newInstance(Employer.class) . It's is possible by copy pasting same jaxb conversion and replacing .newInstance(User.Class) with .newInstance(Employer.Class). But I would like to have the JAXB conversion as Util which can be used for different classes without harcoding the respective Class

I've the XML data like this

```
<User>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>password</password>
</User>
```

What I tried to do is, IF I'm going to call the JaxbUtil.java from UserController, I'll store it as

```
String className = "User.class";
```

If I'm calling it from EmployerComtroller

```
String className = "Employer.class";
```

and then when calling the method, it'll be like

```
JaxbUtil.jaxbXMLToObject(xmlData,className);
```

This is my jaxbXMLToObject method in JaxbUtil.java

```
public static User jaxbXMLToObject(String xmlData,String className) {   //I've passed the xmlString to unmarshaller by StringReader
    User user = null;
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(className);
    return user; // Ofcourse this is after conversion 
}
```

Now I hope you guys can understand what I'm trying to say.

1) .newInstance() doesn't accept String

2) Even if I make it recognize (not possible, just assume), I've to change the return type in method declaration.

Is it possible to make this method common for all xml to different Object conversions without creating seperate method for each Object?

***Solution :***

```
String xmlData; // Assume I've xmlData stored as String
Class<?> classType = Class.forName("com.package.model.Employer");
Employer employer = (Employer) JAXBUtil.jaxbXMLToObject(xmlData,classType);    //JaxbUtil is the Util class where the below code is saved

public static Object jaxbXMLToObject(String xmlData, Class<?> classType) throws ClassNotFoundException {
Object object = null;
    try {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classType);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
        object = (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

So I can now call that Util method by changing the class name in each controller.

***Edit:***  Accepted answer is much standardized than my solution posted above. Refer the accepted answer if you've to implement it.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?.

Comment: Your last 2 paragraph doesn't make sense. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Now you understand how you must post a SO question. Don't make us assume we understand what you're saying. It's preferred that you give us examples for us to give a desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a `ClassLoader` to load a real class from the class name.  Then bootstrap the `JAXBContext` on that class.

---

### UPDATE

> How can I make a return type generic? I mean, each class independent
>   of each other, like User operation have to return User, Employer
>   operation have to return Employer, but neither User nor Employer is
>   having interface or extends relationships

If you can have the parameter be `Class` instead of `String` then you can do the following.  The return type from `jaxbXMLToObject` will be the type that you pass in.

```
public static <T> T jaxbXMLToObject(String xmlData, Class<T> clazz) {   //I've passed the xmlString to unmarshaller by StringReader
    try {
        T result = null;
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlData));
        result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, clazz).getValue();
        return result; // Ofcourse this is after conversion 
    } catch(JAXBException e) {
        // TODO - Handle Exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you will be able to do the following:

```
Foo foo = jaxbXMLToObject(xmlData, Foo.class);
Bar bar = jaxbXMLToObject(xmlData, Bar.class);
```

Comment: How can I make a return type generic? I mean, each class independent of each other, like User operation have to return User, Employer operation have to return Employer, but neither User nor Employer is having interface or extends relationships

Comment: @user1354678 - I have updated my answer with an approach that may work for you.

Comment: Thanks mate. Your update is much standardized than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible answers :

- If you are unmarshalling from xml to object, you need to create the
  objects to unmarshall, that's the point.
- If you want to put the xml file in a string you don't need JAXB.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what are you trying to do. If you want to unmarshalling objects but don't want to code all entitys there are some plugins to create POJOS from xsd.

Comment: Looks like I messed up the question. I've changed the last two paragraphs , take a look